# What can we say about the sign of $x$ in $x(t)=-\int_t^{\infty}(\gamma x(\tau)+b_1)d\tau$

Tags: integration, inequality

I have an integral expression that is given by,
\begin{equation}
x(t)=-\int_t^{\infty}(\gamma x(\tau)+b_1)d\tau=-\gamma\int_t^{\infty}x(\tau)d\tau-\int_t^{\infty}b_1
\end{equation}
where, $x(t)$ is a function, $\gamma>0,b_1\geq0$ are positive constants. I need to be able to comment on the sign of $x(t)$ or what will happen to $x(t)$ in long run? I basically want to establish that $x(t)\leq 0$. I have a rudimentary proof but I want to establish that my proof is indeed correct.

Comment: As written there is a problem if $b_1$ is non-zero, as $\int_t^{\infty}b_1
d\tau$ is infinite for non-zero constant $b_1$.

Comment: What if we differentiate this expression and convert to a differential form?

Comment: I mean differentiating both sides of this equation using Leibniz rule? I mean won't it get converted to $\dot{x}(t) =\gamma x(t) +b_1$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality . Hope it helps!

Comment: If you put the whole thing into a single integral sign, yes. But as it is you are evaluating the integral first. Often it's the same thing, but not here.

Comment: Yeah that was the original question, I have edited my question. @Peter

Comment: @The.old.boy, How is gronwall's inequality helpful here? Kindly shed some light, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating both sides (applying Leibniz rule) gives $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=\gamma x(t)+b_1$$ Substituting $y=x+\frac{b_1}{\gamma}$ now gives us $$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=\gamma x(t)+b_1=\gamma(y(t)-\frac{b_1}{\gamma})+b_1=\gamma y(t)$$ The solution of this equation is $$y(t)=ke^{\gamma t}$$ for some constant k. Hence $$x(t)=ke^{\gamma t}-\frac{b_1}{\gamma}$$ The function to be integrated is actually $\gamma y(t)=\gamma ke^{\gamma t}$, and to be able to integrate this over an interval extending to $+\infty$ the value of $\gamma$ would need to be negative, so the limit as $t \to \infty$ will have the same sign as $b_1$.

Comment: What, if we write, $\dot{x}-\gamma x=b_1$ and now multiplying $e^{-\gamma t}$ both side of this equation, we get, $\frac{de^{-\gamma t}x(t)}{dt}=e^{-\gamma t}b_1$?, then in that case, $\frac{e^{-\gamma t x(t)}}{dt}\geq0$, now integrating this expression over $[t,\infty]$, one obtains, $x(t) \leq 0$. Am I correct in my assessment?